# preg_replace() remove all non-numeric characters EXCEPT trailing x

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following code to remove all non-numeric characters:

```
$num = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $num);
```

I'd like to make it so that it removes all numeric-characters except any trailing X (not case sensitive).

ex:

```
s34kr = 34

xX4rx = 4x

rs5t928X = 5928X
```

Comment: I believe what you mean is "all non-numeric characters except trailing X".

Comment: @AndyLester, I do indeed.

Comment: Can there be more than one trailing X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use look-ahead assertions, coupled with an alternation like this:

```
preg_replace('/\D(?=.)|[^xX]$/', '', $num);
```

It matches a non-digit only if followed by another character or a trailing character that's not 'x'.

**Alternative**

You could consider matching instead:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\d+|[xX]$/', $num, $matches)) {
     $num = join('', $matches[0]);
} else {
     $num = '';
}
```

This matches any number of digits or trailing 'x' and then joins the captured matches together.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$num = preg_replace('/(?:(?!\b\d+[xX]?\b).)*(\b\d+[xX]?\b)?/', '$1', $num);`